# Visual C# - Reading from a text file and separating values in two arrays that hold different values

Tags: c#, arrays, delimiter, streamreader

I'm trying to figure out how to read my text file and separate its values onto an array that holds all the strings and an array that holds all the numbers. I've tried searching on google but can't find anything. Here's what's in my file...

call of duty: Advanced Warfare@17452.78
Batman Arkham Knight@0.0
Carmageddon 2015@734562.68
Halo Ultimate Collection@45629.45
Gears of War: Gold Edition@734562.56
My Little Pony - Zombie Version@452749.21
Need for Speed V=452893.21
FIFA 2016@34981.45
Batman Arkham Asylum@547892.45
NBA 2016=45274.89
dark Sector@54378.23
sniper ellite 3@63478.21
the last guardian=523907.21
the Witcher 3: wild hunt=45294.34
Saints Row 4@53783.55
Mortal Kombat X@423894.54

and this is my code...

```
private void ReadIntoArray()
    {
        try
        {

            const int SIZE = 16;
            string[] titleArray = new string[SIZE];
            //double[] salesArray = new double[SIZE];
            int index = 0;
            StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("GameSales.txt");
            string title = inputFile.ReadLine();
            titleArray = title.Split('@', '=');


            while (index < titleArray.Length && !inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {                                      
                index++;
            }


            foreach (string value in titleArray)
            {
                detailsListBox.Items.Add(value);
            }

            inputFile.Close();

        }



        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your expected output format?

Comment: What does your current output give?

Comment: I have a button that shows outputs by prices first, and a button that shows outputs by titles first. These outputs go onto a listbox

EX for pricesButton..
17452.78 ==> Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare
0.0 ==> Batman Arkham Knight
734562.68 ==> Carmageddon 2015

EX for titlesButton..
Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare ==> 17452.78
Batman Arkham Knight ==> 0.0
Carmageddon 2015 ==> 734562.68

..and so fourth

Comment: is each item of your file on a separate line, or is it one long line of multiple titles.

Comment: each item is on a separate line. lol I just don't know how to make it so on these comments!

Comment: I edited your question to show, just wanted to make sure that I wasn't mistaken

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing will just give you everything between '@' and '=' signs.

You need to use something like Regex.Split to split on either numeric or alpha characters, and find a way to remove the '@' and '=' characters. To get you started, here's a simple example that says you want to use any number of one or more non-digit characters as a delimiter. You'll need a bit more than this for your own purposes obviously:

```
// Split on one or more non-digit characters.
    string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try your method!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you are only reading one line of text. You have a while statement that is doing nothing, you need to move your file processing into that. Your split statement returns an array of values the first being the title and the second your sales information you are not utilizing them. This example should do what you are wanting.

```
private void ReadIntoArray()
{
    try
    {

        const int SIZE = 16;
        string[] titleArray = new string[SIZE];
        double[] salesArray = new double[SIZE];
        int index = 0;
        StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("GameSales.txt");


        while (index < titleArray.Length && !inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            string title = inputFile.ReadLine(); //Note the moving of the file readline into the while statement
            string[] temp = title.Split('@', '='); //Also used a temporary variable to hold the value of the split before assigning it to the array.
            titleArray[index] = temp[0];
            salesArray[index] = double.Parse(temp[1]);
            index++;
        }


        foreach (string value in titleArray)
        {
            detailsListBox.Items.Add(value);
        }
        inputFile.Close();

    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a neat way...

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Series { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your method do this to populate your Movie List.

```
    var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\myfile.txt");
    List<Movie> movies =  new List<Movie>();
    movies.AddRange(allLines.Select(m=> new Movie()
    {
        Series = m.Split(new []{'@'})[0].Split(new []{'='})[0].Split(new []{':'})[0], 
        Name = (m.Split(new[] { ':' }).Length > 1 ? m.Split(new[] { ':' })[1] : m.Split(new[] { ':' })[0]).Split(new[] { '@' })[0].Split(new[] { '=' })[0], 
        Value = decimal.Parse(m.Contains("@")?m.Split(new []{'@'})[1]:m.Split(new []{'='})[1]),
    }));
```

You may be able to simplify the `split` calls. But if you prefer to do it using minimum amount of lines, you can keep them this way.